# How to use .NET dll in JAVA?

Tags: java, interop

My company uses .NET for all development, and we integrate with an ERP made in .NET.
The ERP API is a collection of interops that we simply reference from our .NET project and we are ready to do whatever we want with it.

Recently we are thinking in JAVA development, but we have one concern, the integration with the .NET products we sell.

I've googled a bit and found JNA and JNI.

My questions are:

1. What is the best solution to "use" a .NET dll in JAVA?
2. Do they have limitations in functionality or performance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer JNA over JNI. JNI is more error prone. Boilerplate code you need to write makes it ugly. Also JNI is more C-ish than JNA. I haven't used JNI lately but JNA is hosted at Github, making it more reliable for me. I'm not sure whether JNI will be supported in future. You can see JNA@Github [here](https://github.com/twall/jna). 
In both you need to be get used to type mappings.